# SSL errors using Sauce Labs in Travis CI with Selenium webriver tests (Django project)

Tags: django, selenium, ssl, travis-ci, saucelabs

Trying to get some functional tests running for our Django project but we've hit an error that's proving very difficult to debug. We've attempted to set up [sauce connect](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sauce-connect/), but our build is failing.

You can see the [results](https://travis-ci.org/winecountry/quote-me/builds/327646664) of the build, but here's the stack trace.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_page_load (quote_me.tests.FunctionalTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/winecountry/quote-me/quote_me/tests.py", line 77, in setUp
    self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor="https://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 310, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 466, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 528, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)>
```

The error points me to line 77 in the [`tests.py`](https://github.com/winecountry/quote-me/blob/develop/quote_me/tests.py) file, which is

```
self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor="https://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url)
```

This is all based on [code from Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/), and you can see our [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/winecountry/quote-me/blob/develop/.travis.yml).

```
def setUp(self):
    if "TRAVIS" in environ:
        username = environ["SAUCE_USERNAME"]
        access_key = environ["SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY"]
        capabilities = {}
        capabilities["tunnel-identifier"] = environ["TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER"]
        hub_url = "%s:%s@localhost:4445" % (username, access_key)
        capabilities["build"] = environ["TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"]
        capabilities["tags"] = [environ["TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION"], "CI"]
        self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor="https://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url)
    else:   
        self.selenium = webdriver.Safari()
        super(FunctionalTestCase, self).setUp()
```

Seems like an SSL certificate issue, so I looked into the [`no_ssl_bump_domains` option](https://support.saucelabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/225267468--Bad-Gateway-or-Security-Warnings-When-Using-Sauce-Connect-for-Testing-Web-Applications-over-HTTPS) but didn't seem to help. Also thought something might be wonky because we are using the Django `manage.py runserver` command.

Please let me know if you need additional information, we would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by changing

```
self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor="https://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url)
```

to

```
self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor="http://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url)
```

In case you missed it, we changed the `command_executor` to use `http` rather than `https`.

Comment: Thanks! I've filed a PR to change the example in the Travis documentation: https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/1700

Answer (score 0):

The error does gives us a hint :

```
File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
      encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
```

Apperantly does seems to be a **`encoding`** issue. But as you are using **`Travis CI`** I would recommend you to change the position of the arguments because of the following reasons :

- As per the documentation the `WebDriver implementation` for [**selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) is as follows :

  ```
  class selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=None, browser_profile=None, proxy=None, keep_alive=False, file_detector=None, options=None)
  ```
- As per your code block :

  ```
  self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor="https://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url)
  ```
- You might be trying :

  ```
  self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="https://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  ```

> **Note** : Though we don't have any exposure to your `desired_capabilities`

Comment: I appreciate the help, turned out that our command executor shouldn't have been using `https`, so `"https://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url` became `"http://%s/wd/hub" % hub_url` and boom, no more problem.